# PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Zend_Mail_Message after composer update Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, php, email

Does anybody know how to fix this? When running the index

PHP Fatal error:  **Cannot declare class Zend_Mail_Message**

I already tried

- Deletion of cache, redis, generated folder etc
- Setup upgrade and compilation

Search of class returns only this

```
find . -type f -exec grep "class Zend_Mail_Message" '{}' \; -print

class Zend_Mail_Message_File extends Zend_Mail_Part_File implements Zend_Mail_Message_Interface

./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Message/File.php
class Zend_Mail_Message extends Zend_Mail_Part implements Zend_Mail_Message_Interface

./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Message.php
```

I updated these packages through composer

[image]